# does forwarding a domain on godaddy also forward all links

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, redirect, url

I want to change to a new domain.

I currently have `example.com`

I want to forward to `newexample.com`

If I forward on godaddy.  Will it also forward links for example

Will `example.com/events`

Forward to `newexample.com/events` ?

The reason I ask is I tried, and it only forwarded the root domain and sub links.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2018, GoDaddy does not forward the path to the other domain, it will instead return a 404 if the path doesn't match a short link. They claim they are working on this, but it has been almost 6 months.

My company gave up waiting and built a service called [NavHere](https://navhere.com) that does full path domain forwarding AND short linking if you need it.